# jquery with datatype json doesn't work, but parseJSON of text works

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an asp.net asmx webmethod that returns the following response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">{"field1":"1","field2":"2","field3":"3","field4":"4"}</string>
```

I am calling this webmethod using the jquery ajax function.  If I specify dataType: 'json', I get a parse error.  However, if I omit this statement, it returns successfully and if in the success function I execute jQuery.parseJSON(res.text), it correctly works.

What am I doing wrong?  Is my webservice returning bad header information which is causing the ajax call with dataType: 'json' to fail?

Comment: @Gabe: To be valid JSON, all keys must be quoted.  In Javascript, it's optional.  (except for keywords)

Comment: You don't even need `<?xml ... ?>` and any other meta tags. All you need is data in JSON

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your webservice is returning XML, not JSON.

`datatype: 'json'` requires that the server return pure JSON, not JSON wrapped in an XML tag.

Answer (score 0):

I have always just return the

```
{"field1":"1","field2":"2","field3":"3","field4":"4"}
```

with no xml wrapper and never had a problem.

Comment: How do I remove the xml wrapper?  I created an asynch webmethod in asp.net.  I'm returning a struct object and I have the following declaration for the webmethod:    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]

Comment: sorry not familiar with asp.net, but I would guess you would have to take the method out of a webservice.  Or really just call jQuery.parseJSON() it that works.